# How to play brand mp42 video?

Tags: video, codecs, mp4

Outout of `file`:

```
VID_20190129_195553.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
```

Output of `ffprobe`:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5589e5bb7e40] moov atom not found
VID_20190129_195553.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Output of `mediainfo`:

```
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (isom/mp42)
File size                                : 724 MiB
IsTruncated                              : Yes
```

Got several of these when working on reducing my Google Photos storage space. My Ubuntu can play pretty much any other video files with `vlc` and `mpv`.

Comment: Can you post this file online somewhere so I can have a look?

Comment: Thanks, here is an example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1911oY0BNH5zQkwAf-TC2MKZ-j_zOKZmD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded that file and IMHO it is a corrupt or truncated file. I could neither play it or successfully convert it despite working on it for some time :(

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying! I have quite a few of these and would be interested in ways to un-corrupt them. I sent you the shortest one as they are recording of family moments.

Comment: Oh no! Best bet would be to get the original source if that is possible. FFmpeg could not deal with the files unfortunately so re-encode did not work...